# Reactjs Product Wishlist toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement wishlist feature in reactjs, how do we check if clicked product is already in the wishlist array, here is my addToWishlist function, what logic am i missing here?

```
const addToWishlist = (id) => {
    const check_wishlist = products.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    console.log(check_wishlist);
    if (check_wishlist !== -1) {
      wishlist.push({ ...products.find((item) => item.id === id) });
      setWishlist([...wishlist]);
    } else {
      wishlist.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
      setWishlist([...wishlist]);
    }
    console.log(wishlist);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 error in your code
1: You should not push direct to wishlist
2: wishlist.filter not change value of wishlist

```js
const addToWishlist = (id) => {
    const check_wishlist = wishlist.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (!check_wishlist) {
      const product = products.find((item) => item.id === id);
      setWishlist([...wishlist, product]);
    } else {
      setWishlist(wishlist.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
    }
    console.log(wishlist);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, this is working fine but the only thing is that I am getting empty array on first click then from second click onwards it start adding and removing product in wishlist array... what are we missing!!

Answer (score 0):

Array.filter always returns new list, so you need to set the new list not the wishlist.

```
const addToWishlist = (id) => {
const check_wishlist = wishlist.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
console.log(check_wishlist);
if (check_wishlist !== -1) {
  setWishlist([
   ...wishlist
   products.find((item) => item.id === id);
  ]);
} else {
  const newList = wishlist.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
  setWishlist(newList);
}
console.log(wishlist);
};
```

Comment: toggling isn't working in this function, same product keeps adding in wishlist array, whereas on second click it should remove from array

Comment: I have updated code according to your requirement

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this code still doesn't work, I am getting an empty array in console.